# How to personalize a switch checkbox in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-5

I try to change a switch checkbox in Bootstrap 5.2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>switch</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="form-check form-switch back">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
    </div>
  
    
</body>
</html>
```

The most difficult thing is to change the circle inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle inside is an SVG so to change it I need to use a new SVG

This is a basic switch checkbox Bootstrap code:

```
 <div class="form-check form-switch back">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
 </div>
```

I downloaded an image to the local repository
[image: image to replace a circle]

And I replaced a circle inside a switch checkbox with CSS:
I changed url of a background image

```
.form-switch .form-check-input {
  background-image: url(/ball-147676_640.png);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
  background-image: url(/ball-147676_640.png);
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}

.form-switch .form-check-input:focus {
  background-image: url(/ball-147676_640.png);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

so switch checkbox now is like this:

[image]

focused:

[image]

and active:

[image]